# Successfully initialize XAudio2 in a Visual Studio Community 2019 Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, xaudio2

From '[How to Initialize XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/how-to--initialize-xaudio2#notes-for-windows-store-apps)' in Windows Developer

- Microsoft Windows 10 SDK
- Visual Studio 2019 Community
- Microsoft.XAudio2.Redist NuGet package installed
- Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 4415Y @ 1.60GHz x64
- Windows 10 Pro for Workstations 64-bit operating system

The following code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xaudio2.h>
HRESULT init_audio(void)
{
    IXAudio2* pXAudio2 = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;
    if (FAILED(hr = XAudio2Create(&pXAudio2, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR)))
        return hr;
    IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasterVoice = NULL;
    if (FAILED(hr = pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice(&pMasterVoice)))
        return hr;
    return hr;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    std::cout << std::hex << init_audio() << std::endl;
}
```

directly into a new console solution returns after failing CreateMasteringVoice with the error `800401F0`.

Using any other compiler (GNU, LLVM, Clang) fails to successfully parse XAudio2.h.

Comment: Looks like you have not initialized COM, use `CoInitializeEx` to init COM before calling COM based APIs

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917871/combase-error-coinitialize-has-not-been-called)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/initializing-com-for-a-wmi-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an *Error Lookup Tool*, you'd see that `800401F0` translates to `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED`.

As noted in the comments, you have to initialize COM first:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx( nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED );
if (FAILED(hr))
   // error
```

> I submitted an edit to note that fact on the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/how-to--initialize-xaudio2) page.

You should also look at the [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) for extensive XAudio2 sample code. There's also samples for XAudio2 on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2).

clang/LLVM for Windows v10 works for `xaudio2.h` in the most recent Windows 10 SDKs, and the XAudio2Redist NuGet package header. Just remember that you need to manually integrate the XAudio2Redist NuGet include/lib if you aren't using MSBuild. Otherwise, if you are using the `xaudio2.h` header in the Windows 10 SDK itself, you need to have `_WIN32_WINNT` set for Windows 8 or later.